# how to solve error "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

Tags: c#, wpf

when I run the below code, it is showing the error

> "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

What can i do to solve this issue?

```
public LinqToXml()
{
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"D:\\Data.xml");
    #region Fetch All the Books
    var books = from r in document.Descendants("book") 
                select new
                {
                    Author = r.Element("author").Value,
                    Title = r.Element("title").Value,
                    Genere = r.Element("genre").Value,
                    Price = r.Element("price").Value,
                    PublishDate = r.Element("publish_date").Value,
                    Description = r.Element("description").Value,

                };

    foreach (var r in books)
    {
        com_xdocuments.Items.Add(r.PublishDate + r.Title + r.Author);                            

    }

    #endregion 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Data.xml");
```

Both are same `@"D:\Data.xml"` and `"D:\\Data.xml"`

Comment: `@"D\Data.xml"` and `"D:\\Data.xml"` (no `@` in the latter)